# Flash Font embedding problem

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, fonts, flash-cs3, embedding

I am facing a wired problem with a project. I am embedding Arial font as project is multi-lingual. If I build this project on one of my development machine, Font gets embedded successfully but in any of other machine, project successfully gets published without any warning but font just dont get embedded in SWF.

Note : Project code base is quite big.

What on the earth can prevent flash embedding font ? any ideas guys?

Thanks,
Bhavesh Bagadiya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution long ago for this but just stumbled upon this question again so replying so this can be helpful to others.

Main reason was memory, flex builder stops building code or/and embedding if it runs out of memory during compilation process. increasing memory via following arguments solves problem.

FlexBuilder.exe -vmargs -Xms256M -Xmx512M

Note : One strange observation we had was that its not always solution to increase memory. It requires specific memory settings for machine. on some machine, it runs smoothly even on 256M while some needed 512m, may be depends on other program load on RAM.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to check to make sure that you have EXACTLY the same font installed on those other machines. There are unicode and non-unicode versions of Arial out there. You can always pull up the Font Mapping dialog and seeing if Flash is automatically doing something for you that you may not be aware of. I'm not sure where that dialog is on the PC, but under OS X you can find it under the main application Menu (Flash > Font Mapping).

Comment: Thanks for answer Brander.

I don't aware of any such dialog on Windows, Branden. and Arial is native font of windows n I use Windows XP on all machine so I know Default Arial is same on all machines.

Answer (score 0):

The default arial font contains only the English language. Embed arialuni.ttf which is 22MB in size and contains all languages.